# не найдена ссылка на gluLookAt

Tags: linux, opengl, glut

Cобираю программу и мне выкидывает

```
undefined reference to symbol 'gluLookAt'
```

хотя все библиотеки `openGL`, `glut` подключены

вот **.pro** файл

```
TEMPLATE = app
CONFIG += console c++11
CONFIG -= app_bundle
CONFIG -= qt

SOURCES += main.cpp

# --- linux ---
# хоть заголовочный и не вызываеться всетаки функции вызываються
unix:!macx: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ -lOpenGL

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../../usr/include/GL
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../../usr/include/GL

unix:!macx: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ -lGLEW

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../../usr/include/GL
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../../usr/include/GL

unix:!macx: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ -lglfw

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../../usr/include/GLFW
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../../usr/include/GLFW

unix:!macx: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ -lglut

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../../usr/include/GL
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../../usr/include/GL
```

все загловочные присудствуют в `main.cpp` :

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>

#include <glew.h>
#include <freeglut.h>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Надо ещё библиотеку `GLU` подключить

вот измененный `.pro` файл

```
TEMPLATE = app
CONFIG += console c++11
CONFIG -= app_bundle
CONFIG -= qt

SOURCES += main.cpp

# --- linux ---
# хоть заголовочный и не вызываеться всетаки функции вызываються
unix:!macx: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ -lOpenGL

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../../usr/include/GL
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../../usr/include/GL

unix:!macx: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ -lGLEW

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../../usr/include/GL
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../../usr/include/GL

unix:!macx: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ -lglfw

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../../usr/include/GLFW
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../../usr/include/GLFW

unix:!macx: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ -lglut

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../../usr/include/GL
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../../usr/include/GL


unix:!macx: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ -lGLU

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../../usr/include/GL
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../../usr/include/GL
```